# Symfony2: Setting form label for a checkbox under Bootstrap layout

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

Under the default Symfony layout, I can use the first argument on form_label to set the label text for my checkbox. For example, this:

```
{{ form_label(form.fooCheckbox, 'Foo') }}
```

Correctly renders as:

```
<label>Foo</label>
```

However if I use the [Bootstrap layout](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme), this same argument is ignored:

```
{{ form_label(form.fooCheckbox, 'Foo') }}
```

Renders as:

```
<label>*default humanized label*</label>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured this out after taking another look at the Bootstrap layout file. Instead of rendering my checkboxes like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.fooCheckbox) }}
{{ form_label(form.fooCheckbox, 'Foo') }}
```

The label argument has to move up onto the widget, like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.fooCheckbox, {'label': 'Foo'}) }}
```

I can't spot any mention of this in the documentation - hopefully this will help someone else out.

Comment: You can find it here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-row-view-variables

Comment: @Artamiel To clarify, [form_label arguments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-label-view-label-variables) uniquely don't work under the Bootstrap layout. I can't see any mention of this in the link you posted.

Comment: You sure? I've included in config `- bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` and then in my template file I've modified `form_label` to `{{ form_label(form.email, 'Changed label with bootstrap layout') }}` and it displays `Changed label with bootstrap layout` just fine.

Comment: @Artamiel That's odd - can I see the rendered HTML for your label and input?

Comment: Since I used `form_label` and `form_widget` there is not `form-group` surrounding div. `<label class="control-label required" for="myform_email">Changed label with bootstrap layout</label>` for the label and `<input type="email" id="myform_email" name="myform[email]" required="required" class="form-control" />` for the input

Comment: @Artamiel Sorry - my mistake - I've updated my question as this only applies to the checkbox element. Give it a try and hopefully you'll see the same issue.

Comment: Yup, you're right. It appears it does not set the appropriate attributes either. I will look into it more later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81083/discussion-between-jonathan-and-artamiel).